# WPF Clear a TextBox when a Command executes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button which executes a command and passes the contents of a text box as a command parameter. As part of the Button click/command execution process I want to clear the textbox.
The Textbox text is bound to the selected item of a list view - so I don't believe I can use a bound property to manipulate the text box contents.
What is the best way to acheive the clearing?

Here's the XAML for the Textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbEditOption"
         Grid.Row="3"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Height="25"
         Background="White"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=lvOptions,  
                        Path=SelectedItem.OptionText}"/>
```

And the Button:

```
   <Button x:Name="btnAdd"
        Margin="0 5"
        Width="70"
        Height="30"
        Content="Add"
        Command="{x:Static cmd:CustomCommands.AddOption}">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiParameterConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="cbFilter" Path="SelectedIndex"/>
                <Binding ElementName="tbEditOption" Path="Text"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
   </Button>
```

And finally the code for my command:

```
public static RoutedUICommand AddOption
{
    get { return _addOption; }
}

public static void AddOption_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetupViewModel vm = ((Control)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as SetupViewModel;

    var values = (object[])e.Parameter;

    e.CanExecute = ((int)values[0] >= 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[1].ToString()));
}

public static void AddOption_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetupViewModel vm = ((Control)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as SetupViewModel;
    vm.AddOption(e.Parameter);
}
```

Comment: You can clear the item that's bound to your textbox. If you don't want to do that then it probably should not be be data binded to that variable.

Comment: If the textbox is bound to the selected item of a list view, then you need to set the selected item of the list view to none (or null . . . whatever that needs to be).  Or, don't bind the text box directly to the list view.

Comment: Use a  multi converter and an extra boolean property, on textbox to bind to something else. Or bind to an extra string property

Answer (score 0):

`this.tbEditOption.Text = String.empty;`

However *View* objects aren't necessarily accessible in *view model*.

Also this will break binding since you are changing the source.

Comment: View objects arent necessarily accessible in view model. Also this will break binding

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting the selected item from list view (`SelectedItem = null`) will make the `Text` empty, since `Text` is bound to `SelectedItem.OptionText`.

However this could have side effects.